# App script show id and permissions contained in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this app script code to show the id and its permissions but it throws me the null error,
I don't have much knowledge of app script
Could you help me show me the id and their permissions

```
function showpermisssions() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1tLv4ZkSltTGpK34PcNJ-OQL5UAL67HWo");


  var files = folder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      // Print list of files inside the folder
      file = files.next().getId();
      var id = DriveApp.getFileById(file);
      try {
      
      var access     = file.getSharingAccess();
      var permission = file.getSharingPermission();
      var viewers    = file.getViewers();      
      var editors    = file.getEditors();


      // Logger.log(id);
    }
catch (e) {Logger.log(id); Logger.log(access);Logger.log(permission);};
      
    
       
    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    
 
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [so]. Aquí las preguntas deben ser en inglés. Si prefieres preguntar en español puedes hacerlo en [es.so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code file is an id so it has no methods.

```
file = files.next().getId();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my friend, I feel that you want to tell me with methods

Comment: You're trying to call  a method from File Class in this line `var access     = file.getSharingAccess();` but file in your code is actually just a file id which has no such methods. These are the [methods of the File Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) but file ids have no methods

Comment: solucionado gracias amigo solo he cambiado 
var access     = file.getSharingAccess();
      var permission = file.getSharingPermission();
      var viewers    = file.getViewers();      
      var editors    = file.getEditors();

file por id
var access     = id.getSharingAccess();
      var permission = id.getSharingPermission();

Comment: I don't speak spanish.